# How to Access Android Custom Application Object in simple Java Class which Also has ApplicationContext object?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have created a custom application class like this:

```
class A extends android.app.Application{
    public String abc  = "xyz";
}
```

And I have a simple java class

```
class B {
     private appContext;

     // This constructor is called from activity.
     B(Context ctx){
         this.appContext = ctx;
     }

     private void foo(){
          // want to access Class A's abc String vairable Here...HOW TO DO THAT?????
     }
}
```

How to access Class A's abc String vairable in foo method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the Application class with `getApplicationContext` from `Context` with the good casting

```
((A) this.ctx.getApplicationContext()).abc;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Application` class in Android is a singleton and therefore so is your derived class. Android will create just one instance of your class `A` when it starts your application. Just change

```
class A extends android.app.Application {
    public String abc  = "xyz";
}
```

to

```
class A extends android.app.Application {
    public static String abc = "xyz";
}
```

and you can reference it from anywhere like this:

```
String foo = A.abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are already passing the application context as a parameter and initializing it in the constructor. So all you have to now is to use the context variable to access `abc` of A like the following way: `((A) this.appContext).abc;`

Comment: getApplication() is an Activity method, his class B doesn't extends Activity

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a Context, try passing an instance of the Application class instead.

Something like:

```
class B {
     private Application app;

     // This constructor is called from activity.
     B(Application ctx){
         this.app = ctx;
     }

     private void foo(){
          app.abc; //Do what you want
     }
}
```

And call B like:

```
B b = new B(getApplication());
```

Make sure that this is in `onCreate()` or later.